# Null response while making a POST request using HttpClient from android Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin.android, httpresponse, dotnet-httpclient

Iam sending a POST request from my android app using Xamarin. Iam using `HttpClient` to make the request

Things I have done:

1) Specified Internet permission
2) Tested the request from Postman for google Chrome
3) Debugged the code step by step

Problem:

1) I get the response as `null`.
2) Found the issue might be while receiving the response.

Here is my code:-

```
var resultString = String.Empty;
        var registerContent = new StringBuilder();

        registerContent.Append("DeviceId=");
        registerContent.Append(deviceId);
        registerContent.Append("&");
        registerContent.Append("Name=");
        registerContent.Append(deviceName);
        registerContent.Append("&");
        registerContent.Append("EncodedAccountName‏=");
        registerContent.Append(username);


      var client = DataClient.Instance;
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,new Uri(EndPoints.RegisterDeviceEndPoint, UriKind.Absolute))
        {
            Content = new StringContent("DeviceId=" + deviceId + "&Name=" + deviceName + "&EncodedAccountName=" + username)
        };

     request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        var result = await client.SendAsync(request);
        if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            resultString = HostUrl.GeAuthorizationtResult(result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        }
        return resultString;
```

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: If you post the PostMan request that would help. It does seem like you could just use WebClient to download the string response with a formed URI.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a lot of app-specific code in there, so it's difficult to say what's causing the issue. You can simplify your code by using `HttpClient`'s built-in support for form posts.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("DeviceId", deviceId),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Name", deviceName),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("EncodedAccountName", username)
};

var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUrl, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var resultString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Try this and see if it solves the issue. Otherwise, you'll need to expand on what `HostUrl.GeAuthorizationtResult()` does.

Comment: I tried your solution. But the control skips from 

`var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUrl, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));` 

giving the result string as `null`